# Is it possible to scan a file in reverse from the last line in C?

Tags: c, io, scanf

I am running a simulation and want to add an option to continue evolving from the last iteration of a previous run. In order to do so, I need to read the last 2 lines of data from a file. Is there any way to do this without using fscanf to scan from the beginning of the file?

Comment: You can seek in a file, yes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm relatively new to C and hadn't heard of that function before.

Comment: It can be a pain to scan for lines in reverse. Simplest way IMO is to keep track of the file position where your read should begin. In other words, if you scanned the entire file already, then you track the position of the last few lines as you go. If this is not practical (e.g. you overwrite the file with new contents, or are executing from another process) then consider reading a fixed number of bytes from the end of the file and counting newlines. That will allow you to calculate the file offset for the line and use `fscanf` to read the data again. Or just parse it from your buffer(s).

Comment: If your data is a fixed length then it's easy, seek to the end - the offset of the data you want to read. If not you might find it easier to read from the beginning and just throw away the data you don't want rather than trying to seek around to find the right place to start reading.

Comment: @paddy: I don't see any way to read a fixed number of bytes from the end of the file, without invoking undefined behavior, unless the file is opened in binary mode. Note that in ISO C in text mode, the function `fseek` accepts as an offset only the following: The value `0` or the return value of a previous call to `ftell`. However on POSIX operating systems (such as Linux), this should not be an issue, because there is no difference between text and binary mode.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel in that case, reading one character at a time with `fgetc` and then calling `ftell` after reading a newline would be the way to go. Like I said, it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: A way to do this is something like backward binary search. Seek to some number N bytes before the end of the file and then read all the bytes from there to EOF.  Within that buffer you can find K >= 0 newlines, which demarcate K-1 lines.  If you're looking for L terminal lines and K < L, then double N and try again.  The math will show that there's no asymptotic performance advantage in keeping any info around from the previous iteration. Keep doubling N until the L lines are found.  The other method is to store lines in fixed-size buffers. Then findlng the last L is simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Have the previous run record in another file the `ftell()` values of the last few lines and  other info to note the meta data of the file (e.g. date-time-modified).

A subsequent run can use this info to begin where the prior run left off.

If this side file is missing or does not agree with the current state of things, walk the files with `fgetc()`, `fgets()`, etc. to find where to begin again.